# tail with grep remote log files

Tags: ruby, logging, grep, tail

I have this code to tail remote log files:

```
def do_tail( session, file )
  session.open_channel do |channel|
  channel.on_data do |ch, data|
    puts "[#{file}] -> #{data}"
  end
  channel.exec "tail -f #{file}" 
end

Net::SSH.start("host", "user", :password => "passwd") do |session|
  do_tail session, "/path_to_log/file.log"
  session.loop
```

I want to retrieve only the lines with **ERROR** string in `file.log`, I am trying to call `tail -f #{file} | grep ERROR` but without success.

Comment: What's the output of `tail -f #{file} | grep ERROR` ?

Comment: You can try to add `--line-buffered` to your grep command.

Comment: Maybe you should try something like "bash -c 'tail -f #{file} | grep ERROR'"

Comment: Are you sure that you want to do this in ruby? And I do not see where you would do the grep. But now it is 2 years later, you probably solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want to run `tail -f #{file} | grep ERROR` inside a `.loop`. The `-f` flag tells `tail` to keep streaming data and you are never exiting that stream with Ctrl+C.

You might want to just use a simple Bash command for this, for which you wouldn't even need the `.exec` method. Try something as follows:

```
def do_tail session, file
  @keyword = 'ERROR'
  session.open_channel do |channel|
    channel.on_data {|ch, data| puts "[#{file}] -> #{data}"}
    `grep #{keyword} #{file}`
  end 
end
```